Drawing anti-aliased round dots from vertices in three.js
I am trying to make a grid of points in three.js. I want them to look nice and round, as well as implement distance attenuation. the default PointsMaterial offered by three.js draws square vertices. Therefore I attempt to implement custom shaders.
Vertex:
void main() {
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    gl_PointSize = ${particleSize}.0 / gl_Position.z; // Set the desired point size
}

Fragment:
void main() {
    vec2 coord = gl_PointCoord - vec2(0.5); // Center at (0.5, 0.5)
    float distance = length(coord);
    if (distance < 0.4) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0); // Inside the circle
    } else if (distance > 0.5) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.0); // Outside the circle
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5 - (distance - 0.4) * 0.5 / 0.1); // Fade the boundry
    }

The problem is that this scales with the size of the circle. When the circle is too large the borders become fuzzy, and would still disappear when the circle is too small. One idea is to sample different subpixels. However, since the gl_PointSize isn't passed into the fragment shader it would not know how a shift in the gl_FragCoord would change gl_PointCoord and wouldn't have enough information for subsampling. Is there any way to achieve smooth round dots without using a rasterized texture?

This dots demo https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_points is using texture in this line https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/2ff77e4b335e31c108aac839a07401664998c730/examples/webgl_interactive_points.html#L133 so my assumption is using a texture is the right way.

You should simply use smoothstep, something like float alpha = smoothstep(0.5, 0.4, distance);
